# Get data for specific URL by day and time in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to get a breakdown reporting in Google Analytics for the number of sessions/users during day and time on a specific URL? I was looking at some custom reporting and going down the route of using a pivot table, but I'm not sure if that's overkill for something that can be done directly in GA outright.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom report with page and hour of day as dimensions and sessions as metric.

Comment: ahh, ok. I'll mess around with that. Thanks!